# After Upgrading to PHP Version 7 i get XAMPP Apache Server Error

Tags: php, apache, xampp, php-7

I have latest Xampp installed and i want to upgrade PHP version to PHP 7.
    so i downloaded PHP 7 from..
    http://windows.php.net/download#php-7.0
    VC14 x86 Thread Safe Zip file
    After downloading i extracted zip to custom file and replace full php file and folder to
    ***xampp/php with new php file***
    for php 7 i changed
    ***xamp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf***
    so my new httpd-xampp.conf is

```
LoadFile "E:/xamp/php/php7ts.dll"
   LoadFile "E:/xamp/php/libpq.dll"
   LoadModule php7_module "E:/xamp/php/php7apache2_4.dll"
```

Now When i start Xampp Server its give me Error..

> Error:

*Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
    If you need more help, copy and post this
    entire log window on the forums*

Comment: It says to view the log file. Can you please post it?

Comment: I am pretty sure you dont need these 2 lines in the conf file `LoadFile "E:/xamp/php/php7ts.dll" &   LoadFile "E:/xamp/php/libpq.dll"`

Comment: If you look at the Windows Event Viewer, Apache writes useful info there, even before it gets to opening its own log file

Comment: check your httpd.conf for port used, by default its 80, it might possible that port is used by other application such as skype, if so then change port to 90 and check with http://localhost:90/

Comment: @DavidYue there is no error in error log file. i checked that almost 10 times before post over here

Comment: @user3782114 , Yes i know it may have port issue but i made necessary changes in Skype option (for port)

Comment: @RiggsFolly i don't get your point about 2 line. do you mean need to remove that ?   i think its already in file just change version

Comment: I would definitely remove them, maybe comment them for now `#` but I have never needed to add those 2 lines before

Comment: Have you solve this problem already. What have you done to solve the problem.

Comment: Yes @Oli Soproni B .. i uninstalled old XAMPP and downloaded new one with PHP 7 support. the above trick to change php folder is not worked for me

Answer (score 8):

My system type was x64-based PC, but the PHP that was installed along with XAMPP was x86 (identified from phpinfo() result).  Just by verifying my system type, I was trying to download thread-safe version of x64 and XAMPP failed with same error.  Then after downloading x86 thread-safe version, XAMPP server restarted without any issue.  Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thank you, I spent hours trying to work out why I couldn't start Apache. Using the x86 version was the solution, I guess I have Xampp x86.

Answer (score 1):

check spelling in pathing: xamp > xampp
check pathings are correct. xampp assume it is located in the root.

After installing the new version with php 7, I had to manually go through all conf. files and correct the pathings.

Still loading those files.

Also the my.ini from mysql.

Answer (score 0):

From here you can download the XAMPP with PHP 7 https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the error in `LoadModule php7_module "D:/xampp/php/php7apache2_4.dll"` line. make sure it is `php7_module`