# Apache Server Error about missing files after Upgrading to PHP Version 7 i get XAMPP

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I want to upgrade php version in xampp from 5.6.3 to 7.1. I downloaded php 7 from [windows.php.net](https://windows.php.net/) and I did everything it needs.

by helping [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37182297/after-upgrading-to-php-version-7-i-get-xampp-apache-server-error) I added following line to `httpd.xampp.conf`

```
LoadFile "C:/xamp/php/php7ts.dll"
   LoadFile "C:/xamp/php/libpq.dll"
   LoadModule php7_module "C:/xamp/php/php7apache2_4.dll"
```

Now, my problem is: the zip file content of php 7.1 has no `php7ts.dll` and `php7apache2_4` files, and because of lack of these files `apache` could not run.

[image: capture of php version 7 files]

What do I have to do now?

Comment: I think the quickest way to achive this is to uninstall xamp and just install a new copy of xampp

Comment: @WouterVeen but I have so many project in my xampp, in this way I have to copy all of my projects and connect them to database one by one.

Comment: you don't need to remove the web directory of xampp so you will not lose any projects. And if you keep the same naming for the database there will be no problem at all or just make a dump. As a other tip. Try looking at Vagrant, I find it quite easier to use then xampp

Comment: thank for your good suggestion, but I like to know why php versions does not have those files.

Comment: @WouterVeen I forgot to say this, none of the php versions in php.net has those file. why?

Comment: Make sure you got the thread safe version of php the non thread safe version does not have the php7apache2_4.dll file [VC14 x64 Thread Safe](https://windows.php.net/download#php-7.0)

Comment: @WouterVeen yes I'm sure about it. I downloaded five version of php. none of them have those two file that I mention it.

Comment: I just download the file php-7.0.29-win32-VC14-x86.zip. in the root directory the file libpq.dll and php7apache2_4.dll are both present as is the same for 7.1 and 7.2. As long as you take the thread safe version.

Comment: @WouterVeen what about `php7ts.dll`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168654/discussion-between-mohammad-aghayari-and-wouter-veen).

Comment: Yes this one is also in the zip. All the files you are looking for a in the thread safe version of php.